# Redux items in an array are having their ids updated

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, expo

I'm working on a react-native (expo) events app and I'm encountering a problem with the ids of my mock events being updated when they shouldn't be only if they're *integers*, when the id's are *strings* I don't have this issue.

The basic flow is I show a list of events, when a users presses on that event they're brought to that event view. I do this by using **eventInFocus** and **events* reducers and finding the event I need in the **eventView** container.

When I press on a particular event all the event ids get updated and its difficult to debug because it states that the previous state already had the mixed up ids, which is very confusing because there are no issues in rendering the items in the home view (loop through array, use id as key).
If I select the first event, i  get an an error that the event can't be found, if I select any of the other 2 events, the event ids are randomly updated.

**events reducer**

```
const defaultEvents = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'my birthday',
    date: new Date(),
    repeatAnnually: false,
    wallPaperSource: null
  },{
    id: 1,
    name: 'yosemite trip',
    date:  new Date(),
    repeatAnnually: true,
    wallPaperSource: null
  }, {
   id: 2,
   name: 'trip to dublin',
   date: new Date(),
   repeatAnnually: false,
   wallPaperSource: null
}];

const event = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EVENT_EDITED:
      if(state.id !== action.event.id){
        return state;
      }
      return action.event;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function events(state = defaultEvents, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case ADD_EVENT:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: action.event.id,
          name: action.event.name,
          date: action.event.date,
          repeatAnnually: action.event.repeatAnnually,
          wallPaperSource: action.event.wallPaperSource || null
        }];
    case EVENT_EDITED:
      return state.map(e =>
        event(e, action)
      )
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**eventInFocus reducer**

```
function eventInFocus(state = {}, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case "UPDATE_EVENT_IN_FOCUS":
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.event);
    case VIEW_EVENT:
      return Object.assign({}, action.event);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**eventContainer** - container around each item in the list (home view)

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    ownProps
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onPress: (event)=> {
      dispatch(viewEvent(event));
    }
  }
}
```

**viewEventContainer** - for the single event view

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const {events, eventInFocus } = state;
  viewEvent = find(events, e => e.id = eventInFocus.id);
  return {
    event: viewEvent,
    ownProps
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, state) => {
  return {
    onEditEvent: (event) => {
      dispatch(editEvent(event));
    }
  }
}

const EventViewContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(EventView);
```

**viewEvent action**

```
export const viewEvent = (event) => {
  return {
    type: VIEW_EVENT,
    event
  }
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing about redux? Are my reducers poorly structured? The confusing part for me is why it only happens with integers and not strings. Thank you in advance!

State when I press on an event, as you can see the previous state already had the mutated ids for the events [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a line with the bug in your code:

```
viewEvent = find(events, e => e.id = eventInFocus.id);
                                   ^
                                   here
```

As you can see `state` is being mutated on every invocation of `mapStateToProps`.